# How to improve/find alternative to -filter parameter when searching large amounts of information in Powershell?

Tags: algorithm, powershell, search, filter, parameters

I'm a mid level sysadmin at a fairly large institution and relatively new to powershell. I'm trying to write a PS script that can use search about 2000 first/last name pairings in AD and return their ID numbers (SamAccountName).

Technically the script works, I use get-aduser and apply a filter parameter that matches the name to get the user AD object, then filter output by the SamAccountName property, which does give me what I need. The problem is we have so many users in AD that it can take up to 30 seconds for the filter to match just one name, which is actually slower than doing it manually. On top of that this puts such a massive strain on our servers that several other proprietary tools that query AD just stop functioning while the script runs.

I was just wondering if there was either a faster way of doing this, or if there was some sort of way to tell the -filter parameter what type of algorithm to use that could make the process more efficient.

Comment: This question might be better on-topic at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Anyway, please edit the question and include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates slowness.

Comment: Some attributes are not indexed, so that means they could be slower to be matched in the filter expression. One thing to consider is your -server parameter. Are you connecting to the server that gives you the best response time? Another thing to consider is that if you are doing 2000 `Get-ADUser` queries then maybe you are better served to do one larger `get-aduser` query that captures all users and then use `.where({$_.sn -eq "last name" -and $_.givenname -eq "first name"})` to find each user. If the slowness is in querying AD, then reduce the number of queries.

Comment: I personally have good results with `get-aduser -filter {sn -eq "last name" -and givenname -eq "first name"}`. Maybe there are other attributes or `where-object` commands in your code that can be optimized.

Comment: as vonPryz implied ... without code to pair with your description of your problem ... getting you a useful response would require telepathy. [*grin*] **_please, add the code in question to your Original Post._**

Comment: Sorry, probably would've been better to post it originally, I just didn't think about asking till I got home and couldn't remember everything I did. I'll add it in the morning, but also much appreciation for all the suggestions so far!